# Matching two arrays of distance values

Tags: math, geometry, distance

I have an arrays of distances (source), e.g.

```
[1, 2, 1, 5, 2]
```

and I want to match that array against a second one (target) where

- the distances may be totaled up together
- there are missing and/or additional entries
- the distances are (proportionally) different

I think it's a bit more obvious in pictures.

The first row shows the source array - the second row shows the target array matching the first line in a possible "match position" (black = hit, yellow = missing, blue = additional). The distance between the lines are the values of the array.

The second image in each case shows a more algorithmic way to the match (thanks to @MBo hint to "merge"). Each green section is a match - if it's wider then 1, then there are missing lines, if it's higher than one there are additional lines in the target array.The count of rectangular section + 1 is the hit count.

So the results here are:

###### For target array `[2, 1, 5, 2]`

[image: [2, 1, 5, 2]]
[image: [2, 1, 5, 2]]

```
5 hits, 1 missing
```

###### For target array `[3, 5, 1, 1]`

[image: [3, 5, 1, 1] - 1]
[image: [3, 5, 1, 1] - 1]

```
4 hits, 2 missing, 1 additional
```

[image: [3, 5, 1, 1] - 2]
[image: [3, 5, 1, 1] - 2]

(same target array but different position as before)

```
3 hits, 3 missing, 2 additional
```

###### For target array `[2, 2, 6, 1, 1]`

[image: [2, 2, 6, 1, 1] - 1]
[image: [2, 2, 6, 1, 1] - 1]

```
3 hits, 3 missing; 3 additional
```

[image: [2, 2, 6, 1, 1] - 2]
[image: [2, 2, 6, 1, 1] - 2]

(same target array but different position as before)

```
4 hits, 2 missing; 2 additional
```

Not as a picture, but

```
[4, 2, 10, 4] => same as the first result of [2, 1, 5, 2]
```

(there are many results per target array but I'm interested only in those with the most matches and least missings/additional).

While I can think of a naive approach (use any combination of two lines of the source and line them up with any combination of two lines of the target), I wonder if (and hope that) there are better solutions.

It seems like a sort of an assignment problem to me - but I can't get my head around it.

So far I've tried the naive approach only.

I need to tolerate measurement errors and inaccuracies, too. At the moment that clashes a bit with the proportional conversion (the errors sum up to even bigger ones), but so far it seems like it could work that way.

---

Here's the "merge"-part:

```js
const d = 30;
const source = document.getElementById("source");
const target = document.getElementById("target");
const examples = document.getElementById("examples");

function example(src, trg) {
  const btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.style.display = "block";
  btn.innerText = src.join(", ") + " / " + trg.join(", ");
  btn.onclick = () => {
    source.value = src.join(", ");
    target.value = trg.join(", ");
  };
  examples.appendChild(btn);
}
example([1, 2, 1, 5, 2], [2, 1, 5, 2]);
example([1, 2, 1, 5, 2], [3, 5, 1, 1]);
example([1, 2, 1, 5, 2], [2, 2, 6, 1, 1]);


function start() {
  const src = splitInts(source.value);
  const trg = splitInts(target.value);
  
  const result = document.getElementById("result");
  const ctx = result.getContext("2d");
  result.width = d * (src.length + 2);
  result.height = d * (trg.length + 2);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, result.width, result.height);
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  for (let idx = 1; idx <= src.length; idx++) {
    ctx.moveTo(d * idx, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(d * idx, result.height - d);
    
    const txt = ctx.measureText(src[idx - 1]);
    ctx.fillText(src[idx - 1], d * idx + d / 2 - txt.width / 2, d / 2);
  }

  const x = ctx.measureText("x");
  for (let idx = 1; idx <= trg.length; idx++) {
    ctx.moveTo(0, d * idx);
    ctx.lineTo(result.width - d, d * idx);
    
    const txt = ctx.measureText(trg[idx - 1]);
    ctx.fillText(trg[idx - 1], d / 2 - txt.width, d * idx + d / 2 + x.width / 2);
  }
  
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  const [hits, missing, additional] = match(src, trg, ctx);
  ctx.stroke();

  document.getElementById("hits").innerText = hits;
  document.getElementById("missing").innerText = missing;
  document.getElementById("additional").innerText = additional;
}

function splitInts(values) {
  return values.split(/[ ]*,[ ]*/g).map(v => parseInt(v));
}

function match(source, target, ctx) {
  let sourcePos = 0;
  let targetPos = 0;

  let sourceLength = source.length;
  let targetLength = target.length;

  let totalSource = 0;
  let totalTarget = 0;

  let hits = 1;
  let missing = 0;
  let additional = 0;
  
  let lastSourcePos = 0;
  let lastTargetPos = 0;

  do {
    if (totalTarget != 0 && totalSource == totalTarget) {
      totalSource = 0;
      totalTarget = 0;

      missing--;
      additional--;
      hits++;

      if (ctx != null) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 200, 0, 0.4)";
        ctx.fillRect(d * (lastSourcePos + 1), d * (lastTargetPos + 1), d * (sourcePos - lastSourcePos), d * (targetPos - lastTargetPos));
        lastSourcePos = sourcePos;
        lastTargetPos = targetPos;
      }
      
      continue;
    }

    if (totalTarget > totalSource) {
      if (sourcePos >= sourceLength) break;      
      totalSource += source[sourcePos];
      sourcePos++;
      missing++;
      
      if (ctx != null) {
        ctx.moveTo((sourcePos + 0) * d, (targetPos + 1) * d);
        ctx.lineTo((sourcePos + 1) * d, (targetPos + 1) * d);
      }
      
      continue;
    }

    if (targetPos >= targetLength) break;
    totalTarget += target[targetPos];
    targetPos++;
    additional++;
    
    if (ctx != null) {
      ctx.moveTo((sourcePos + 1) * d, (targetPos + 0) * d);
      ctx.lineTo((sourcePos + 1) * d, (targetPos + 1) * d);
    }
  } while (true);

  missing += sourceLength - sourcePos;
  additional += targetLength - targetPos;

  return [hits, missing, additional];
}
```

```html
<p>
  (!) shit in - shit out<br />
  <label for="source">source: </label><input id="source" value="1, 2, 1, 5, 2"><br />
  <label for="target">target: </label><input id="target" value="2, 2, 6, 1, 1">
</p>

<p id="examples">
  Examples:<br/>
</p>

<p><button onclick="start()">start</button></p>

<p>
  hits: <span id="hits">-</span><br/>
  missing: <span id="missing">-</span><br/>
  additional: <span id="additional">-</span><br/>
</p>

<canvas id="result" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that your data is not simple arrays because you are showing absence of values and different positions of values - more like intervals.

In this case you can perform merging of two interval lists in order.
For example, interval from the first list started, then interval from the second list started, you compare values and make result for interval intersection. Then the first one ends while the second one continues - so additional value is detected and so on...

P.S. Perhaps physical sense of data might make things more clear.

Comment: "merge" was a great hint that leads to new images (where I try to show that merge algorithm in the case of my arrays).
I think in that way I can simplify the single "matching test run" a lot (though I still struggle how to resize one of the arrays and how to get every possible combination in a reasonable amount of computation time)